# In the MVC programming pattern, which category does the following code fall under?

Tags: model-view-controller

If I have some code which is will HTTP request a remote website and extract data from it, or login to this website and extract data from it; what would I put this under? The model or the controller?  I'm think that it is a model, because the controller should talk to the user and call upon my models to do stuff.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model is correct.  The data crunching portion should be left to the models.  The controllers direct the traffic between the models and views. Finally, views are used to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably do this a view or controller. If you will need to do any large manipulation with the data, you could create and action that makes a request and then manipulates the data and then pass that data onto a view. If you will need simpler operations, and depending on your framework, you can make the request in the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

You would possibly use all of the View, Model and controller. But if you don't want to display the result, it would likely be just the controller and model.

For example, the controller code would have an ActionResult method which would call your remote website.

e.g. your model

```
public class RemoteWSData
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

your controller:

```
public ActionResult GetRemoteWebsiteData()
{
    RemoteWSData model = repository.GetRemoteWebsiteData();

    string code = model.Code;
    string name = model.Name;
}
```

with the repository above being a data access class. This data access class would contain references to the connections required to access the data or server and get these values from a web.config file.

Comment: What would a data access class be? A model, view, or controller?